# How to use Task Queue in GAE flexible env?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Currently I'm doing migration from GAE standard environment to flex environment. In the standard env app, we have included task queue and cron.

[This](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml) ensures that we can use cron on flexible env but I'm unsure about the task queue.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Task Queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#task_queue) section of [Migrating Services from the Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating):

> The Task Queue service has limited availability outside of the
>   standard environment. If you want to use the service outside of the
>   standard environment, you can sign up for the [Cloud Tasks alpha](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1g6yRocQ3wtdTArfO4JX8DoqOhYmsoTVgrlFnS0mV1bo/viewform?edit_requested=true).
>
> Outside of the standard environment, you can't add tasks to [push
>   queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/#push_queues), but a service running in the flexible environment can be
>   the target of a push task. You can specify this using the
>   [`target`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#specifying_the_worker_service) parameter when adding a task to queue or by specifying
>   the default `target` for the queue in [`queue.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/queueref).
>
> In many cases where you might use pull queues, such as queuing up
>   tasks or messages that will be pulled and processed by separate
>   workers, [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/) can be a good alternative as it offers
>   similar functionality and delivery guarantees.

Comment: So we can do the same procedure for adding tasks to push queue by defining a separate microservice and putting the queue information on queue.yaml file, right?

Comment: Yes, if that service (the one adding the tasks to the queue) is a standard env one. I'd make the standard service the `default` one.

Comment: Actually we gonna change all the services from standard to flex including the default one.

Comment: Then try the alternatives mentioned in the quote.

Comment: in the answer above?

Comment: Outside of the standard environment , we can't add tasks to task queue.

Comment: Did I need to sign up for task queue alpha? I'm still unsure of using task queue, crib in flexible environment..